# RecordRTCPromisesHandler: RecordRTCPromisesHandler Interface cannot be instantiated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recordrtc

I am new to `muaz-khan/RecordRTC`, first time using it, copy/pasted the default implementation below and it already throwing error.

Why is this code snippet showing this error?

[image]

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import RecordRTC, { RecordRTCPromisesHandler } from "recordrtc";

export const useRecorderPermission = (
    recordingType
) => {

    const [recorder, setRecorder] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        getPermissionInitializeRecorder();
    }, []);

    const getPermissionInitializeRecorder = async () => {

        let stream = await (navigator).mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true,
        });

        let recorder = new RecordRTCPromisesHandler(stream, {
            type: recordingType,
        });

        setRecorder(recorder);

    };

    return recorder;

};
```

https://prnt.sc/DpbBXr_9Fp0F

Comment: I took your code and tweaked it and got it working with a simple demo in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-hellman-utnp2c?file=/src/App.tsx). I don't really know what I did differently to get it working, but maybe it will help you.